# the launcher disappears when the mouse pointer is positioned on it what should i do?

Tags: launcher

when i move the mouse pointer to the launcher the launcher disappers and all of desktop

this video show my problem : https://youtu.be/at3NeuAGoQA

Comment: Looks like the desktop compositor crashes when you click on the launcher. What's your Ubuntu release? Did you change or mess around with the Compiz settings somehow?

Comment: my ubuntu 16.04.3 .  no,I didn't

Comment: Thanks. Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. You'll have to find the log file of Unity and look inside for a crash reason (i. e. add it to your question too). Unfortunately I don't know where to find it but I'm sure the search function of Ask Ubuntu or Google can help you find out.

Comment: This appears to be same problem as [question put on hold as unclear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992752/ubuntu-updates-1-4-2018). I think the video on this question makes the closed question clear.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. No solution but switch to XFCE so far... :-( That's sad - I really love Unity, it's otherwise perfect, IMHO.

Comment: I also have the same problem as exhibited in the YouTube video posted above.. kern.log shows this message numerous times:  Jan  5 06:40:26 Lab-Linux kernel: [53035.351646] compiz[4895]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f1e6260deb6 sp 00007ffeb97909b0 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7f1e6202b000+82d000]

Comment: I was also affected and [The answer is chosen on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992353/ubuntu-16-04-jan-3-2018-update-causing-screen-access-issues) which worked for me.