# Launcher toolbar defect after ubuntu update earlier today

Tags: 16.04, updates, launcher, unity-dash

I installed the latest ubuntu update today and ever since my gui, specifically the side Launcher toolbar is not functioning. When hovering over with mouse, it disappears for a few seconds and then re-appears, but won't let me click on any of the icons.  The Dash will not work at all. Has anybody experienced this problem? I don't see any similar topics in the questions.  Thanks!

Using 64 bit version, tried to follow tips in terminal provided in your linked related issue post, still experiencing same problems.  Issue appears to be related to latest system update as others have reinstalled ubuntu and it works fine until performing the system update again, then the problem returns.

I rebooted after first installing the updates, but, did not check to see if the original kernel was still available. Now, it seems as though I can't even get to those Advanced options at this time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 Jan 3 2018 update causing screen/access issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992353/ubuntu-16-04-jan-3-2018-update-causing-screen-access-issues)

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu version? Have you tried rebooting and selecting grub's **Advanced options** menu and then selecting an older kernel version to test with?

Comment: After applying system update did you reboot and see if the original kernel is still in Grub's advanced options menu?