# error after fresh instalation ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse

I had an error on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Because i installed year ago or more i decide to reinstall it. But even now after updates is doing the same problem. After login to new session if I try to touch with mouse the icons bar all disappear ...even the right up corner with date and start disappear for few second.If i move mouse in the middle they stay in place. Was fine after fresh installation but last night i run updates and now is the same problem like before . If anyone have idea what is going on here, i will really appreciate a little help. i have a video of what is going on but I don't know where to post it..
Thank you

Comment: Seems to be a fast developing bug. There is a bug report of it here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1741447

Comment: thank you. any idea who I need to contact? who will be able to fix this?

Comment: Well, the bug forum has information on the progress being made at this very moment, and who it is that is working on it. There are also work-around solutions until a bug fix is issued in the answer to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-latest-updates-compiz-segfaults

Comment: Thank you man. I am not really good with this stuff. For the moment some friend give me same help and i move all icons on the top bar and is nothing on the right side(working this way) but  I'd  like to come back to the normal version of 16.04 LTS. If you hear something when is fix it please let me know and I will reinstall it again. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Sangre Sani sent me this fix (from my post, [Ubuntu 16.04 Jan 3 2018 update causing screen/access issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992353/ubuntu-16-04-jan-3-2018-update-causing-screen-access-issues/993569#993569) - there is another answer there as well but I didn't use it) and it seems to work:

The solution that worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

That updated the mesa thing to the newer version and the problem is fixed!

Comment: I am updating from main server...thank you again