# ubuntu 16.04 encounters an internal error

Tags: compiz, shutdown, unity-dash

I have sent an error report and examined the details of the error shown in the popup window announcing the error.  The first few lines of the error report were as follows:
Executable Path -
/usr/bin/compiz
Package compiz-core 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-oubuntu1
  Crash//compiz crashed with SIGSEGV
.top_unity_support_test.0

Consequences of the crash:
  Restarting the computer just comes up with the internal error  message.
  The launch bar has limited function.
  The DASH does not work, so I cannot bring up programs such as UPDATE.
  I can bring up other programs on the launch bar; but when the pointer goes back and forth between desk top - with whatever program is running on the desktop (e.g., firefox) - the screen blanks to the empty back ground and then the display comes back.
  When I try to shut down the the computer via clicking on the shut down line is the menu in the upper right corner of the screen, it will not shut down.  The only way I can shut things down is by manually pressing the power button on the computer.

Some possibly useless information:

This is a dual boot machine with Windows XP in the other partition.  The windows partition seems to be working OK (knock on wood).

I recently installed Oracle's Virtual Box and have been trying to configure a windows XP guest.  So far it has been a lot of trouble and possibly may lie behind my problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after updates 2018-01-04, compiz segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 Jan 3 2018 update causing screen/access issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992353/ubuntu-16-04-jan-3-2018-update-causing-screen-access-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here since recent update. When touching with mouse pointer the Launch bar disappears and comes up again after a few seconds. Some icons cannot launch a program. Cannot logout or shutdown via de GUI.  Opening a Terminal window, I can shutdown and/ or reboot but allways get the message that Ubuntu has encountered an internal error.(/usr/bin/compiz ).   Tried a lot of things as suggested by # contributors without success. Installed the Gnome desktop and all problems are solved!
My laptop: Dell Vostro 13 ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit