# Ubuntu Dock keeps Disappearing

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, favorites

The favorites bar (Ubuntu Dock) on the left hand side of my Ubuntu 19.10 desktop keeps disappearing. Sometimes it will be days, sometimes several times a day. I have found references here: [Taskbar keeps disappearing!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993073/taskbar-keeps-disappearing) and here: [Ubuntu 16.04 Jan 3 2018 update causing screen/access issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992353/ubuntu-16-04-jan-3-2018-update-causing-screen-access-issues) for previous versions.

I had this problem on previous versions as well, but it got better and now it has returned in the latest and greatest. :(

Excerpts from syslog:

```
Jan 18 20:14:07 westeros geoclue[26909]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Jan 18 20:14:07 westeros systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Jan 18 20:14:07 westeros systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Succeeded.
Jan 18 20:14:29 westeros xdg-desktop-por[27953]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 18 20:15:13 westeros pulseaudio[27668]: W: [pulseaudio] resampler.c: Support for resampler 'src-sinc-best-quality' not compiled in, reverting to 'auto'.
Jan 18 20:15:29 westeros xdg-desktop-por[27953]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 18 20:15:57 westeros gnome-shell[28046]: Some code accessed the property 'discreteGpuAvailable' on the module 'appDisplay'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jan 18 20:16:29 westeros xdg-desktop-por[27953]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 18 20:17:01 westeros CRON[27097]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 18 20:17:29 westeros xdg-desktop-por[27953]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 18 20:18:12 westeros PackageKit: daemon quit
Jan 18 20:18:12 westeros systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Jan 18 20:18:12 westeros systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Jan 18 20:18:29 westeros xdg-desktop-por[27953]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros gnome-shell[28046]: # _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros dbus-daemon[27676]: [session uid=1000 pid=27676] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.388' (uid=1000 pid=27139 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --window " label="unconfined")
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros systemd[27649]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros dbus-daemon[27676]: [session uid=1000 pid=27676] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros systemd[27649]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros gnome-shell[28046]: # _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros gnome-shell[28046]: # watch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros gnome-shell[28046]: # unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (active: 0, establishing: 1)
Jan 18 20:19:06 westeros gnome-shell[28046]: # watch_established: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0)
Jan 18 20:19:29 westeros xdg-desktop-por[27953]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

I press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f2</kbd> and then enter `r` in the command window to restart the GNOME Shell and the favorites bar returns.

There needs to be a better solution than this.